# Is there any trick or method to count recursion calls on paper(with larger numbers)?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

Hi everyone it is my first question here! I would like to ask about some tricks how can we count recursive calls in a paper, without using computer? The language in example is Python 3.xx. In this example if I get larger number like 11 how can I count number of stars in this example "easily"?

```
def func(numb):
    print('*', end='')
    if numb <= 1:
        return False
    for i in range(numb):
        if func(i) and numb%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

func(11)
```

I found too uneffective, to write everything as the program running, especially if it is on a test, too time consuming.
Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods of counting recursive calls; this one basically is iteration, I guess, you do

```
T(n) + T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) ... // in which T(n) is the complexity of the recursive call
```

Substitution will lead to the same result and master theorem is useless here, so that's the best you can do, and since every one of your calls is linear this ends up being (worst case scenario, of course):

```
n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) ... + 2 // since you end at 1
```

But you can actually reduce your recursive calls if you do this:

```
if numb%i == 0 and func(i): // you won't reach func(i) if num % i != 0
```

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot rewrite code, I have only a pen and i have to give the number of stars at the end of function, so if I correctly give "n" maybe I can find out something.

Comment: I gave you the answer before that last comment. n is your numb; so in your example 11.

Comment: but if you have to give the number of stars, you'll just have to iterate over it yourself, since techniques like this can only really approach it.

Comment: @RichardT basically replace the n with your numb, tbh. Since the code isn't optimized that's how many iterations it will do.

Comment: I found a connection... if numb is NOT a prime number, it write out 6 stars and False....If the numb is prime number: numb = 3 --> 6 stars; numb = 5 --> 18 stars, numb=7 42-->stars... but detected with running the code...on paper it is still too long I think...

Answer (score 0):

Please check these function.

```
def recursion(numb):
    if(numb<1):
        return False
    print('*'),
    numb-=1
    recursion(numb)

recursion(11)

print('')

def recursion1(numb):
    if(numb<1):
        return False
    for i in range(numb):
        print('*'),
    print('')
    numb-=1
    recursion1(numb)

recursion1(11)
```